# How to resize images client-side with nodeca/pica and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to resize image before sending it to the server to a canvas in React using nodeca/pica library:

```
import pica from 'pica'

let resizedCanvas = <canvas height={500} width={500}/>

  pica().resize(myImage, resizedCanvas, {
  unsharpAmount: 80,
  unsharpRadius: 0.6,
  unsharpThreshold: 2
}).then(result => console.log(`resize done!  ${result}`))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

but I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: stages.shift is not a function or its return value is not iterable
at processStages (index.js:508)
at init.then (index.js:549)
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that I should not use JSX for building the canvas. The following solution worked great:

```
const resizedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
resizedCanvas.height = 500
resizedCanvas.width = 500
```

Comment: don't forget to accept your answer in SO